# Tortoise-orm with FastApi Fetching data from db is blocking/Sync instead of asynchronous/non-blocking

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi, tortoise-orm

Using fastapi with tortoise-orm==0.19.3. There're like 25,000 records of the table `Server`.

I'm fetching all of them with the endpoint `/servers/` like this.

```py
@server_router.get("/servers")
async def get_servers():
    ret = await ServerPydantic.from_queryset(Server.all())
    return ret
```

There's no pagination and offset, I do this for test purpose.

There is another endpoint:

```py
@server_router.get("/servers-test/{s}")
async def test(s:int):
    print(f"sleeping for {s} seconds")
    await asyncio.sleep(s)
    return {"test": "test"}
```

I make requests to the endpoint`/server`, then I quickly make two more requests with the endpoints `/servers-test/{s}`:

- `curl http://127.0.0.1/servers` , this will take some time, around 4-5s
- `curl http://127.0.0.1/servers-test/5`, right after the first request
- `curl http://127.0.0.1/servers-test/0` right after the previous request

I can tell immediately by looking at the print statement in the functions the last requests are not processed at all, it's blocking by the call to `/servers` until the first request finishes. Only then the other two start to run.

If i do

```py
@server_router.get("/servers")
async def get_servers():
    asyncio.sleep(30)
    print("sleeping done")
    ret = await ServerPydantic.from_queryset(Server.all())
    return ret
```

Basically I just added the `asyncio.sleep(30)`. Then I repeat the steps mentioned above.

- `curl http://127.0.0.1/servers` , this will take long time since `asyncio.sleep(30)`
- `curl http://127.0.0.1/servers-test/5`, right after the first request, it get's served right away
- `curl http://127.0.0.1/servers-test/0` right after the previous request, it get's served immediately

If I make a request after 30 seconds, then requests get blocked again. So obviously, the `Server.all()` blocks the I/O. It's not expected. Am I doing anything wrong? I've searched on Google and Tortoise-orm Github issues, and yet there's no related info found.

updated:
I've tried with sqlalchemy, the same thing happens. So it's not Tortoise-orm related I geuess.

I've tried with this:

```py
# some sessions and schemas setup are not shown here.
@app.get("/serversv2", response_model=ServerList)
async def get_all_servers(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    result = await session.execute(select(Server1))
    servers = result.scalars().all()
    return {"servers": servers}
```

It still blocks other requests.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what your `Server` object is - but if that is a synchronous call, them it will block.

It does not matter if you pass its results to an async call in Pydantic: the call to `ServerPydantic.from_queryset` will only take place *after* `.all()` had returned.

Since you did not post all your code, I can't be that assertive in the answer - but maybe the `Server` object itself is iterable, and "does the right thing" if you don't call `all()` on it? Then you just pass the Server object itself to the `from_queryset` call (which sounds like what should be done, anyway - the return of an `.all()` method are the query results themselves, not a queryset).

Comment: The server object is just a tortoise orm or sqlalchemy model.

Comment: so, have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: the thing is you have to call `all()` to return a queryset needed by the `from_queryset` as stated in the document. Server is just a model object , not queryset object. I'm still not able to figure it out. My guess is the serialization part. I'm not so sure about it though. Probably Py-spy will shine some light on it.

Comment: `all` just don't sound like a method to create a query set - rather, a queryset method to fetch concrete results. Nonetheless, it is what is happening there: the `all` call is made in a synchronous context. It may be that it yields a lazy object that will be driven asynchronously, but from what you report, I don't think it is so.

Comment: BTW, this could be a lot easier for me to answer if you add the actual code to instantiate your `Server`, along with example data.